# Loop adding hyperlinks referencing correct cell coordinates but on the wrong sheet

Tags: vba, excel, loops, hyperlink

This code is meant to find a cell on the current sheet that corresponds to a cell on the 'Main' sheet, then insert hyperlinks that work both ways between the two cells. The actual text displayed on both hyperlinks should be the number value found in the cell on the 'Main' sheet.

I keep running into two problems:

a. 'Object not supported by this property or Method' error (line location noted below)

b. 'inserts hyperlink to the correct coordinates but on the current sheet, instead of the 'main'

All the examples I'm looking at online use sheet.hyperlink.add so I'm confused why I'm receiving this error using the same syntax

Here is my code so far

```
Sub hyperlinkinsert()

Dim Sh As Worksheet

Dim r As Range
Dim R2 As Range

Dim w As Range
Dim W2 As Range

Dim S1 As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 0

    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    i = i + 1

        If i > 3 Then

                S1 = Sh.Cells(1, 1).Text

                Set r = Sh.Cells.Find(What:="Chosen Value")

                    If Not r Is Nothing Then

                        Set R2 = r.Offset(0, 1)

                        Set w = Sheets("Main").Cells.Find(S1)

                            If Not w Is Nothing Then

                                  Set W2 = w.Offset(0, 2)


                                      R2.Formula = "=Index('Main'!H12:H284,Match(A1,'Main'!F12:F284,0))"

                           '**** ERROR MSG OCCURS HERE  ****
                                      Sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=R2, Address:="", _
                                      SubAddress:=Sheets("Main").W2, TextToDisplay:=R2.Value

                                      Sheets("Main").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Main").W2, _
                                      Address:="", SubAddress:=R2, TextToDisplay:=Sheets("Main").W2.Value

                            End If

                    End If


                Set r = Nothing
                Set R2 = Nothing
                Set w = Nothing
                Set W2 = Nothing

        End If


    Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions from chris's answer applied to the code, plus an additional one:

```
Option Explicit

Sub hyperlinkinsert()
   Dim wsC As Worksheet, wsM As Worksheet, celC As Range, celM As Range, adr As String

   Set wsM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")

   For Each wsC In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      If wsC.Index > 3 Then

         Set celM = wsM.UsedRange.Find(What:=wsC.Cells(1, 1).Text)
         Set celC = wsC.UsedRange.Find(What:="Chosen Value")

         If Not celM Is Nothing And Not celC Is Nothing Then

            Set celM = celM.Offset(0, 2)
            Set celC = celC.Offset(0, 1)

            adr = "'" & wsC.Name & "'!" & wsC.Cells(1, 1).Address

            celC.Formula = "=Index(Main!H12:H284,Match(" & adr & ",Main!F12:F284,0))"

            If Not IsError(celC) Then
               wsC.Hyperlinks.Add celC, "", celM.Address(External:=True)
               wsM.Hyperlinks.Add celM, "", celC.Address(External:=True)
            End If
         End If
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

---

Assuming: value for Cell A1 in the formula should be extracted from the current sheet

Comment: Works great, thank you! Interesting to see how you organized the code as well, it looks much cleaner.

Comment: I made a small update to include the sheet name in `adr` - this will properly reference the cells in each sheet (this was the extra issue, and I  think I removed it at some point while testing)

Answer (score 5):

There are two issues in your code

1. When using a `Range` object, it already includes the worksheet context, so for example rather than `Sheets("Main").W2` use just `W2`
2. The `Hyperlinks.Add` method, `SubAddress` parameter needs to be a address string, including the worksheet reference.  So for example rather than `SubAddress:=R2` use `SubAddress:=R2.Address(External:=True)`

Putting this together, your Hyperlink code should be

```
Sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=R2, Address:="", _
  SubAddress:=W2.Address(External:=True), TextToDisplay:=R2.Value

Sheets("Main").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=W2, Address:="", _
  SubAddress:=R2.Address(External:=True), TextToDisplay:=W2.Value
```